The number of the double cosets $K\backslash G/H$ equals $ \langle \pi_{G/K} , \pi_{G/H} \rangle$
$H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$. $\pi_{G/K}$ is the permutation character of the set $G/K$ (the left cosets).
My thoughts
I think we are finding the number of the $K$-orbit on the set of left cosets $G/H$, so I tried using the Burnside lemma.
\begin{equation}
\langle \pi_{G/H},1 \rangle_{K} = \text{number of $K$-orbit}
\end{equation}
I think it might be helpful to use the Frobenius reciprocity, but I cannot continue.

Where did you find that statement?

Your approach should work, you just need to figure out what is $\operatorname{Ind}K^G(1_K)$  You should be a little more careful with your notation, as you don't actually mean $\pi{G/H}$ in your use of Burnside's lemma, you mean the restriction, and there are many different trivial representations, one for every group, and if you don't make these implicit things explicit in your notation, then it is easy to get confused with what things mean.  Abuse of notation is fine if no confusion arises, but when you use Forbenius reciprocity, confusion is easy.

We have an isomorphism $\mathbb C[K\backslash G] \otimes_{\mathbb C[G]} \mathbb C[G/H]\cong \mathbb C[K\backslash G/H]$ given by $e_{Kg}\otimes e_{g'H}\mapsto e_{K(gg')H}$  Since $\dim \mathbb C[K\backslash G/H]$ is the number of double cosets, we wish to compare the dimension of the left hand side to the inner product of the characters.
For any $\mathbb C[G]$-modules $U, V$ with characters $\rho_U$ and $\rho_V$ we have that $\langle \rho_U,\rho_V\rangle=\dim_{\mathbb C}\hom_{\mathbb C[G]}(U,V)$, and therefore that $\langle \pi_{G/K}, \pi_{G/H}\rangle=\dim_{\mathbb C} \hom_{\mathbb C[G]}(\mathbb C[G/K], \mathbb C[G/H])$.  Thus, we wish to show that
$$\dim_{\mathbb C} \hom_{\mathbb C[G]}(\mathbb C[G/K], \mathbb C[G/H])=\dim_{\mathbb C}\mathbb C[K\backslash G] \otimes_{\mathbb C[G]} \mathbb C[G/H]$$
For this, we can show that
$$\hom_{\mathbb C[G]}(\mathbb C[G/K], \mathbb C[G/H])\cong C[K\backslash G] \otimes_{\mathbb C[G]} \mathbb C[G/H].$$
We leave establishing this final isomorphism as an exercise.

Since we are finding the number of the $K$-orbits, then
\begin{equation}
\langle Res_K^G(\pi_{G/H}) , 1_K \rangle_K = \langle \pi_{G/H}, Ind_{K}^{G} 1_K\rangle_G = \langle \pi_{G/H}, \pi_{G/K} \rangle_G \end{equation}
I used the Burnside lemma and Frobenius Reciprocity theorem.
